# Calendar weekdaySymbols monday first

Tags: swift, swift5, nscalendar

What is the most elegant way to convert `Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols` array to the array where Monday is the first element (Index of Monday in the array would be 0)? The most "swifty" way possible.

Comment: Rotation is a very inefficient and cumbersome way to do this particular task.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop your array first element and add a collection with just the first element to it:

```
let array = Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols.dropFirst() + [Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols.first!]
print(array) // "["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]\n"
```

Note that if you are planning to use it without the rest of the date components you should use [`standaloneWeekdaySymbols`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293469-standaloneweekdaysymbols)

> Stand-alone properties are for use in places like calendar headers.
>   Non-stand-alone properties are for use in context (for example,
>   “Saturday, November 12th”).